# can't remove class after click again

Tags: javascript, dom-events, toggle

I tried to color the text I clicked on by gave them a class and besides the text I click on the original color is back again, but when I click on the text twice the class can't be removed. I use toggle class for this issue but doesn't work.

```
.red {
    color: red;
  }
```

```
<ul>
    <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  </ul>
```

```
const txts = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');
  const txtColor =(txt)=> {
    txt.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if(e.target.classList.contains('txt')) {
        txts.forEach(txt => txt.classList.remove('red'));
        e.target.classList.toggle('red');
      }
    });
  }
  txtColor(document.querySelector('ul'));
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve], particularly the HTML so we can debug it.

Comment: I did, I added class red on css to gave the text color

Comment: So when you click on an item that one should be red, and all the others should not be red?

Comment: Right. But when I clicked again the color won't be removed

Comment: @ShaefulAmin - I think Andy is probably referring to the CSS - which you have not included. I'm fairly certain the CSS is important based upon your question.

Comment: The `ul` element has **no classes**, but you **used contains**

Comment: contains refers to li

Comment: @
Randy Casburn there you are, I updated all the codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the main list element, and the list items, and then attach one listener to the list element so you can use [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch item click events as they "bubble up" the DOM.

When an item is clicked remove the `red` class from all the items and , depending on the conditional parameter you pass to `toggle`, (does the `classList` contain a `red` class) [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) the `red` class.

```js
// Cache the elements
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');

// Add a listener to the list
ul.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Destructure the nodeName and classList from the
  // the element we clicked on
  const { nodeName, classList } = e.target;

  // Check if it's a list item
  if (nodeName === 'LI') {

    // Does the list item contain a red class?
    const isRed = classList.contains('red');

    // Remove all the red classes from all the items
    lis.forEach(li => li.classList.remove('red'));

    // And depending on the answer to `isRed`
    // toggle the class on or off
    classList.toggle('red', !isRed);

  }

}
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
.txt:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
</ul>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: It works, but I don't understand  const { nodeName, classList } = e.target;

Comment: I added a link. It's called "destructuring assignment". Basically I extract the `nodeName` and the `classList` from the element that was clicked on. I could have written `const cn = e.target.className` and used `cn` as the variable in the function, but this shorthand makes things a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, I could make this work.

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('text')
});
```

```css
.text {
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. Please see the comments in each section.

```
const txts = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');

const txtColor = (txt) => {
  // click on li item
  txt.addEventListener('click', e => { 
    // if target contains class txt, which in case, it's hard coded
    // this will always return true
    if (e.target.classList.contains('txt')) {
      // remove red class for each list item with class txt
      // in this line, it removes every 'red' class on each list item
      txts.forEach(txt => txt.classList.remove('red'));
      // Then toggle 'red' class if it's not present on the target
      // Toggle does as it say, if its not present, it adds the token
      // if it's present, it removes it.
      // since the statement above ALWAYS removes the red class,
      // Toggle will only always add the 'red' class
      
    }
    e.target.classList.toggle('red');
  });
}

txtColor(document.querySelector('ul'));
```

If I'm right, I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // if target doesn't contain red class, then remove all red class from the list
    
    if(!e.target.classList.contains("red")) {
        document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(e => e.classList.remove("red"))
    }
    // toggle red class to the target
    e.target.classList.toggle("red")
})
```